# How do I convert a EPS , DOC and PPT document to a preview image in PHP?

Tags: php, image

How do I convert a EPS , DOC and PPT document to a preview image in PHP?

I need to display the image thumbnails in the list of items uploaded, how can i get the thubnail images of EPS, doc and PPT files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some library that is capable of rending these.

PHP on its own will not know how to render these file types. You could try converting the Word document and PowerPoint files to HTML, then convert the HTML into an image, there is [software](http://bit.ly/aCdfEu) that can this for you.

As for the EPS, isn't that an image anyway? So you need to use a library like GD or ImageMagick into a meaningful format that they can resize for you.

Comment: I want to make it runtime as pdf is being done using imageMagick

Comment: That makes no sense. There is no reason why you can't do this at runtime.