# Creating front page jpg from office file

Tags: php, ms-office

I want to show a user a preview of a file by creating a jpg of the first page.

Much like that what you see in Windows (see below, .pptx example).

[image: Preview of what I want]

Is there a way to do this using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions. The problem is that PHP can't render the Office file formats. So you don't get an image. There are some libraries like [Apache TIKA](http://tika.apache.org/) that can render and work with these office formats. But then you need a wrapper and you have to call it over the shell or something else.

Otherwise here in the Post is an answer how to do it with a software to convert it to HTML and then to an Image.

[How do I convert a EPS , DOC and PPT document to a preview image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683865/how-do-i-convert-a-eps-doc-and-ppt-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php)